# inline element doesn't work after jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html-lists

This is my Code :

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
  <ul>
    <li>Setting</li>
    <li id="copyright">CopyRight</li>
    <li id="e_copyright">&copy CopyRight Daarkoob Data Processing Co.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
    background: #000;
    height: 35px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #999;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#top ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#top ul li {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#top ul li#e_copyright {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#top ul li#copyright").click(function(){
    $("#top ul li#copyright").hide(function(){
      $("#top ul li#e_copyright").show();
    });
  })
});
```

when I click on **CopyRight** , the third li ( e_copyright ) show in bottom of **Setting**, but I guessed it will appear inline of Settinf beacause I set **li's** display inline.

how to change code to appear third li when second one clicked ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach : here is a code to add a `li` line after clicking on the copyright line. It will occurr only once using `one` JQuery event.

```
<div id="top">
  <ul>
    <li>Setting</li>
    <li id="copyright">CopyRight</li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#top ul li#copyright").one('click',function(){
    $("#top li:last").after('&copy CopyRight Daarkoob Data Processing Co.')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#top ul li#copyright").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(function () {
        $(this).next().show().css({
            "display": "inline"
        });
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D7PDq/)

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique, so ID selectors are the most specific, and non-redundant. No need to use parent selectors as well, that just adds unnecessary overhead. See the updated code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyright").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("#e_copyright").show().css('display','inline');
    });
});
```